# jQuery expand/hide with cookie

Tags: html, cookies

I have the following code. I actually need a cookie that remembers the current state of the div even if the user reloads the page. Thank you a lot for your help!

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".menu i").hide();
    jQuery("#showmenu").click(function(){
        if(jQuery(".side-menu").width() > "87"){
            jQuery(".side-menu").animate({width: '-=205px'});
            jQuery(".main-section").animate({'margin-left': '-=205px'});
            jQuery(".logo").text("2");
            jQuery("span.text").hide();
            jQuery(".menu i").show();

        }
        else {
            jQuery(".side-menu").animate({width: '+=205px'});
            jQuery(".main-section").animate({'margin-left': '+=205px'});
            jQuery(".logo").text("1");
            jQuery("span.text").show("slow");
            jQuery(".menu i").hide();
        }

    });

});
```

And this is the div

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side-menu">
    <div class="logo">
      Vi Dairy
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:15px;color:white;"></i><span class="text">test</span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:15px;color:white;"></i><span class="text">test</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-history" style="font-size:15px;color:white;" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text"> test</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:15px;color:white;" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text"> test</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:15px;color:white;" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text"> test</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gears" style="font-size:15px;color:white;" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text"> test</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: [This is an easy to use jquery cookie plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) that allows you to read and write cookies - you can set  a state on button click and then read that state on document ready to apply on page load (or use your server side language to apply iy on load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **setCookie** function to create the Cookie and **getCookie** to get the value.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

JQuery Example

```js
//To set a cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');

//Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

//Create expiring cookie, valid across entire page:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

//Read cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null

//Delete cookie by passing null as value:
$.cookie('the_cookie', null);

// Creating cookie with all availabl options
$.cookie('myCookie2', 'myValue2', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'example.com', 
         secure: true, raw: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp). If you save something in a localstorage item, the cookie disappears when you close your browser and will stay when you refresh the page.